# VirtualBox vs Qemu/KVM performance - Ubuntu 22.04 guest on top of Ubuntu 22.04 host

Tags: virtualbox, qemu

I'm currently using Virtualbox in Ubuntu 22.04 for VMs running also Ubuntu 22.04. I'm not using it for games, so no need for PCI passthrough. Only web browsing or some P2P network transfers. My Virtualbox VMs are configured for Execution Engine VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Pages Active and Paravirtualization Interface is KVM.

I've noticed some videos on youtube that suggest QEMU /KVM is much faster than Virtualbox, with many people pointing out that QEMU is using KVM. I'm a bit confused as VIrtualBOx also claims KVM usage.

So my question: Is there any noticeable difference in performance when running Guest Ubuntu on Host Ubuntu when using QEMU/KVM and VirtualBox.

Virtualbox is super easy to use, seamless experience available on most Hosts like Windows or Linux. Not sure if switching to QEMU/KVM is worth it. I'm not using PCI passthrough, I'm just thinking about increasing the performance of disk operations that result in faster snap firefox starting and general less laggy experience even on a bit slower host hardware.

Best regards